# Find tbody count

Tags: html

I'm using a `for` loop to populate html table. How can I get the count of the all the `tbody` tags in tables based on its `className`?

Sorry might be dumb question but couldn't find how ?

Comment: front-end or back-end? if front-end using a specific library or "plain" JS?

Comment: was trying to paginate(front-end) keeping tbody count...using Jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*If you are using jQuery*, you can do this way:

```
alert($('tbody.yourClass').length);
```

**Or vanilla Javascript:**

```
var els = document.getElementsByTagName('tbody');

var counter = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < els.length; i++){
  if (els[i].className === 'yourClass') counter++;
}

alert(counter);
```

Comment: thanks Sarfraz will try this ...and see if i can complete pagination with this counter

Comment: oh yea i tried to accept it long back and it just said u cant do this right away :(....but thanks now i can

Answer (score 1):

In case you are not using jQuery you can try the one below:

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName("TBODY");
    var len = a.length;
    var resultArr = [];
    var tBodyClassName = "something" //You can update it your className.
    for(var i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
        var b = resultArr[i];
        if(b.className == tBodyClassName)
        {
            resultArr.push(b);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Cybernate..I'm trying to paginate keeping track of tbodies...i'm using JQuery...

Comment: In that case you this solution is not the efficient one.

Comment: no probs thanks for the reply may be it'll help in a different situation :)